# How to change http header using nginx

Tags: nginx, http-headers

We have a problem that a backend system requires the parameters of the Content-Type http header to be in a certain order.

For example (note the position of the type="text/xml"):

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="-=Part.0.57208b0e-3948-44e6-b15a-9bbfa5f0074b=-"; type="text/xml"; start="<0>"; start-info="text/xml"
```

Should be (note the position of the type="text/xml"):

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/xml"; boundary="-=Part.0.57208b0e-3948-44e6-b15a-9bbfa5f0074b=-"; start="<0>"; start-info="text/xml"
```

I have found the module HttpHeadersMoreModule. The challenge I have is that I need to change the order of the string, but preserve the values. Any suggestions how to solve this with nginix?

Regards, nidkil